# Help me understand this PHP code

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am a PHP beginner.

When going through a PHP script I found:

```
if(preg_match('/(?i)ID=(\d+)/',$input)) {
    // id found
}
```

I want to know what does `(?i)` mean ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?i)` is a [**in line modifier**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php) which makes the match case insensitive.

It is equivalent to adding a `i` after the closing delimiter:

```
if(preg_match('/ID=(\d+)/i',$input))
                         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The below line is finding matching pattern in $input string like ID=any number.

```
preg_match('/ID=(\d+)/i',$input)
```

Example matching patterns are
ID=2
id=34
Id=23